# Change look and feel when button is active and hover

Tags: css

I don't understand the below requirement and how to achieve it.

**Thanks to all who put effort. @Carlene solution is working only I've to modify as per requiremnet**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submit-form">Submit Answer</button>
```

I tried the below, but it doesn't reflect any changes.

```
button#submit-form:hover {
    fill:#ffffff;
    outline: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 14px;    
}
```

Comment: Could you provide code sandbox example?

Comment: @Satif i've no sandbox. but you can refer this https://codepen.io/seme332/pen/reJOwo/ and this is what more or less im trying to achive with different style

Comment: _“The button fill is #ffffff”_ - that is likely referring to the background color; `fill` is a thing with SVG images, but SVG is not even involved here.

Comment: _“I tried the below, but it doesn't reflect any changes.”_ - that might be due to the classes the element already has, and the formatting that gets applied through them - these are probably part of some CSS framework’s formatting. Instead of showing use mere snippets that probably lack context, please provide a proper [mre] in cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
button#submit-form {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 14px;  
    color: #697070;
}

button#submit-form:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/carlene_cannon_conner/pen/XWrxpmW

Note that anything you want to add or override during an on hover should be put in the second block. As this css is only applied during a hover state, otherwise it will use what ever css you have in button#submit-form.

background-color refers to the background colour of the button and color refers to the colour of the font in the button.

By outline do you mean border? In which case you may want something like:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

1px refers to the thickness of the border, solid refers to the kind of border, e.g. dotted or solid and black refers to the colour you would like this can also be a hex value instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `fill` parameter in CSS. Use `background` or  `background-color` instead, and instead of `outline` use `border`.

Answer (score 1):

**Change :**

```
button#submit-form:hover {
    fill:#ffffff;
    //...
}
```

**To:**

```
button#submit-form:hover {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    //...
}
```

Comment: box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px  yourColor ;